Unable to forward and receive internet traffic through Raspberry Pi 4 Wifi AP
There are many tutorials out there showing how to set up a Wifi AP using Raspberry Pi 4, all with different configurations. I am trying doing it with my specific setup as following:

RPi4 acting as Wifi AP. It is installed with Kali for Raspberry. It has an eth0 interface connecting to the internet through my home Wifi router (let's call this router HomeWifi). This RPi4 has a wlan0 which I want to use as the Wifi AP interface receiving local network traffic from other devices. So, basically, this RPi4 sits between my HomeWifi and the devices I want to connect to the internet.

A Debian laptop is sitting behind the RPi4, wanting to access the internet. Let's call this device TestDevice


Below are the various configurations I have set on RPi4:
1 - In /etc/network/interfaces:
auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
   allow-hotplug eth0
   iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
   address 192.168.220.1/24

2 - In /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf:
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211

hw_mode=g
channel=6
ieee80211n=1
wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0

auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

ssid=mypirouter
wpa_passphrase=password_for_mypirouter

3 - In /etc/init.d/hostapd:
DAEMON_CONF=/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

4 - In /etc/dnsmasq.conf:
resolve-file="/etc/resolv.dnsmasq"
server=1.1.1.1
interface=wlan0
bind-dynamic
dhcp-range=192.168.220.50,192.168.220.150,12h
dhc-option=option:router,192.168.1.1
log-queries
log-dhcp


5 - In /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.1

A note here on why I do this: I reference the NOTES section in the page man dnsmasq. It says
...in order to configure dnsmasq to act as cache for the host on which it is running, put "nameserver 127.0.0.1" in /etc/resolv.conf....
6 In /etc/resolv.dnsmasq
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8


7 In /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1

8 In /etc/sysctl.conf:
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

9 - Below is the settings for iptables:
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1:32]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1:32]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:248]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT

*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [9023:800718]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [8673:816768]
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT


The result:
After running the following services on the  RPi4:
sudo systemctl start hostapd
sudo systemctl start dnsmasq

I confirm both services are running on RPi4.
Then, on my TestDevice, I connect to the SSID mypirouter sucessfully. Running ifconfig on TestDevice shows that it has been allocated an IP of 192.168.220.141, well within the configured range above.
Now, when I tried ping www.google.com on TestDevice, I got the following error:
PING www.google.com 56(84) bytes of data
From TestDevice (192.168.220.141) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From TestDevice (192.168.220.141) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
...

However, if I try to ping the RPi4 through its static IP with
ping 192.168.220.1

I am able to receive a response like this:
PING 192.168.220.1 56(84) bytes of data
64 bytes from 192.168.220.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.46 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.220.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=2.84 ms
...

At this point, my suspicion is that something is wrong with the iptables. But I am not sure how to fix this. Any advice is very much appreciated.

You have DHCP set to configure an out-of-subnet address as the default gateway. Is it really set up like that?

@DanielB Do you mean this line dhc-option=option:router,192.168.1.1? If so, yes, that is indeed in the config. 192.168.1.1 is the gateway of my HomeWifi.

That might be, but it cannot be the default gateway of your mypirouter Wi-Fi. Or do you actually not want a separate subnet?

@DanielBThank you for your prompt. I did not understand the dhcp-option correctly. After digging a bit more,I commented it out and now it works. The RPi4 default gateway is the same as its static IP.

In your dnsmasq configuration, you have the following line:
dhc-option=option:router,192.168.1.1

…but also the following IP pool for DHCP clients:
dhcp-range=192.168.220.50,192.168.220.150,12h

With the usual 255.255.255.0 subnet masks, this means 192.168.1.1 is in another subnet. But that’s not the worst thing; it is actually also not “on-link”. Instead, this router is in a separate network segment and is not directly reachable.
If you simply remove this option, dnsmasq will still send it, but figure out the address to send by itself. That works most of the time, if dnsmasq is running on the default gateway itself.

If you didn’t actually want to create a different network segment with your access point, you could also bridge the Wi-Fi AP interface and the wired interface, removing the need for dnsmasq and any iptables setup altogether.
